# Can I configure Messages for Mac to receive messages sent to my phone number?

Tags: messages, macos

Is it possible to configure Messages for Mac in such a way that it receives text messages sent to my mobile phone number?

Currently on the Mac I can receive only messages sent to my Apple ID, but on my iPhone I can receive messages sent to both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 6, your phone number and your Apple ID will be unified, so when you'll receive a iMessage or a Facetime call, they will appear on all your devices (iOS and Mac OS).

More info [here](http://www.theverge.com/2012/6/11/3078598/ios-6-unified-apple-id-phone-number).

So I think you just need to wait until this fall to resolve your problem !

Comment: I'm really wishing iOS 6 and ML were released at the same time.